# Remove "Border" on a Div

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using two JavaScript libraries for a web project , one for having a slide (bootstrap-slider.js) and another to handle the event Swipe on some div ([jquery.touchSwipe.min.js](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin))

On the jquery.touchSwipe.min.js library i can set a **excludedElements** property

```
$(".div_Oggetti").swipe({

    swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {

    if(....){


            switch(direction){
                case "left" : 

                    ...

                break;
            }
        }

    },
     threshold:100,
     excludedElements : ".slider-handle,button, input, select, textarea, a, .noSwipe"
  });
```

but when I insert the class of the slide ball (.slider-handle), on the elements to be excluded from the swipe event, an edge id added to the slide ball(blue on chrome, black squares on firefox)

[image] [image]

I can't remove it with *border: none*, or with *text-decoration: none*

how do I remove that border? 
thanks

Comment: Can you paste into a fiddle? have you tried border: none !Important;?

Comment: Do you have a demo? Can you try resetting the `outline` property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) property to `none`:

```
.slider-handle {
    outline: none;
}
```